# Determine if window is visible with High CPU

Tags: c, winapi, screenshot

**Background**

I am trying to screenshot a specific window, however the OS where I need to accomplish this has very high CPU usage and sometimes my application determines this window as visible however in the screenshot it is either not shown or half drawn.

**My Understanding**

Since the CPU usage is very high it will not be able to provide enough resources to the process which opens this specific window. Therefore the check for window visibility succeeds it may just mean that the window was initiated for creation but not drawn yet (given the lack of resources).

**My Code**

```
HWND hWnd = FindWindowExA(0, 0, NULL, programdata->caption);
if (hWnd)
{
    if (IsWindowVisible(hWnd))
    {
        RECT rect = { 0 };
        GetWindowRect(hWnd, &rect);

        // if window size also matches requirement then
        TakeScreenshot();
```

**Question**

Is there any better way that I can determine if the window was fully drawn and visible to the human eye?

Comment: Why not using WindowFromPoint function in a loop?

Comment: Since I can't always predict the position that this window will appear.

Comment: Get the rect with GetWindowRect().

Comment: For this I need hWnd and in the case of GetWindowRect I don't have it.

Comment: As a side measure you could try to level up a priority of the application's process.

Comment: In any case, you need a handle to a particular window, no matter what API you call to detect whether the window is redrawn or not.

Answer (score 2):

> if the window was fully drawn and visible to the human eye?

To take screenshot you don't need the window to be visible. You only have to copy from its context. So just do `GetWindowDC()` and use it.

If you really need to check if it's "visible to human eye", you must also ensure that the window is at the top of Z-order. Otherwise, it could be overlayed by some other window.

If you want to check if window was fully repainted, you can test its `GetUpdateRect()` value.

Comment: generic Win32 windows are not automatically backed by bitmaps or something like that so "copying from its context" is not magically going to work for a window that is invisible or occluded. The OP could try sending the window the WM_PRINT message which tells Windows to paint the target window into a given HDC but in my experience this message tends to not work.